# How to compare 2 categories to the whole categories using facet in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridview, facet

Hi would like to compare two categories to whole categories using facet_grid or facet_wrap or another function in ggplot. For example i would like to compare statistics of Hospitals 3 and 4 to the whole hospitals.

```
Hospital<-c("Hosp1","Hosp1","Hosp1","Hosp1","Hosp1",
            "Hosp2","Hosp2","Hosp2","Hosp2","Hosp2",
            "Hosp3","Hosp3","Hosp3","Hosp3","Hosp3",
            "Hosp4","Hosp4","Hosp4","Hosp4","Hosp4")
Disease<-c("D1","D1","D2","D2","D3",
           "D1","D1","D1","D3","D3",
           "D3","D3","D2","D2","D3",
           "D1","D1","D2","D2","D2")

data<-data.frame(Hospital,Disease)

plot<-ggplot(data, aes(x=Disease,fill=Disease))+
  geom_bar()+facet_grid(~Hospital)+coord_flip()
```

Using facet_grid, I have a graph that compares the four hospitals, which I do not want.

I rather want something like this with facets without going through "grid.arrange", because I want to display all disease categories (even if they are null) for all graphs (in order to easily compare) and I don't want the x.axis label to be displayed for each graph because it takes a lot of space

```
wh<-ggplot(data, aes(x=Disease,fill=Disease))+
  geom_bar()+coord_flip()+labs(title = "whole hospital")

H3<-ggplot(data[data$Hospital=="Hosp3",], aes(x=Disease,
      fill=Disease))+ geom_bar()+coord_flip()+
  labs(title = "hospital3")

H4<-ggplot(data[data$Hospital=="Hosp4",], aes(x=Disease,
       fill=Disease))+ geom_bar()+coord_flip()+
  labs(title = "hospital4")

grid.arrange(wh,H3,H4,ncol=3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this based on `gghighlight`

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

data_all <- 
  data %>% 
  mutate(Hospital = "Hosp_all") %>% 
  group_by(Disease) %>% 
  summarise(total = n())

data %>% 
  filter(Hospital %in% c("Hosp3", "Hosp4")) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = Disease, fill = Disease))+
  geom_col(data = data_all, aes(Disease, total),  fill = "gray80")+
  geom_bar()+
  coord_flip()+
  facet_wrap(~Hospital)+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This a great idea, but unfortunately I have more than one thousand hospitals in my real dataset

Comment: Hmm, are you sure you want to compare all hospitals in one graphic? You might be better off comparing each disease by all hospitals on a facet by disease basis

Comment: I want to see if the disease profil of two hospitals (my hospitals of interrest) differ from the national profil (thats is the profil of disease of more than a thousand of hospital including my hospitals of interest)

Comment: So If I understand you correctly you only want to compare the disease profile of two individual hospitals with the grouped profile of all (1000) other hospitals?

Comment: Exactly, you understand.

Comment: OK I've modified the answer to limit the faceting to the two hospitals you are interested in and added a second background bar for 'all' hospitals. See what you think.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is not too large, one way to bind the data frames together, add another column that would indicate the dataset (or hospital) then plot with facet :

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)


rbind(data,subset(data,Hospital == "Hosp3"),subset(data,Hospital == "Hosp4")) %>%
mutate(hospital=rep(c("whole hospital","Hosp3","Hosp4"),
c(nrow(data),sum(data$Hospital == "Hosp3"),sum(data$Hospital == "Hosp4")))
) %>%
mutate(hospital=factor(hospital,levels=c("whole hospital","Hosp3","Hosp4"))) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=Disease,fill=Disease))+ geom_bar()+coord_flip()+
facet_wrap(~hospital,scale="free_y")
```

[image]

Comment: My dataset is a bit large, more than 7 millions of rows